# Detect right clicks on a RichEditableText

Tags: apache-flex, right-click, richeditabletext

I am currently implementing [squiggly](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/squiggly.html) in a flex application to enable spell checking. Due to certain requirements, I can not use SquigglyUI to hook onto my spark RichEditableText. I have successfully used `com.adobe.linguistics.utils.TextTokenizer` to tokenize and highlight mispelt words.

I would like to be able to let the user rightclick on a mispelled word and show a list of suggestions in the context menu using `getSuggestions`.

I have tried to attach a listener to my RichEditableText:

```
richtexteditor.addEventListener("rightClick", showSuggestions);
```

And this is my event handler:

```
private function showSuggestions(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace('hi there');
}
```

The problem is when debugging the application, I never get the trace in my console as the rightclick event is never dispatched. In addition, I need to detect the word the user has right clicked on. How can I go about doing this and how can I detect right clicks?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was add an event handler to the contextmenu property of the richeditable text:

```
richtexteditor.contextMenu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, listener)
```

This will listen for the right-click of the mouse (Flex4.5)